# Form antd onFinish not getting triggered

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a onFinish function that modifies the values/json sent to the backend API.

Here is how it looks..

```
    const onFinish = formProps.onFinish!;

    formProps.onFinish = (values: any) => {
        // Ignore display only fields.
        

        ["a", "b"].forEach((k: string) => {
            delete values[k];
        });

        onFinish(values);
    };
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <Form {...formProps} layout="vertical" onFinish={onFinish}>
```

This is working perfectly fine in localhost where i use `npm run dev`. However - it does NOT work in dev environment where i run `npm ci` followed by `npm run build`

The console logs confirm that the onFinish is only being called in localhost and not in dev.

Interestingly console logs is that in the environment where this works (shown first below) - looks a bit different

[image: works]

in the environment where this does NOT work - i see the logs in a different format (shown second below)

[image: does NOT work]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a minifier issue. After changing the function name from onFinish to handleFinish - it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I am using antD onFinish on dev and prod server and it is working totally fine for me.
I don't know what is formProps in your case but this is how i use antD form.

```
const handleFinish = (values) => {
// You can do any kind of manipulation here
     console.log(values) // here it will work totally fine
}
<Form onFinish={handleFinish}>
// your form items
   <Button htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
</Form>
```

I have attached a codesandbox example for the form
https://codesandbox.io/s/bps4ef?file=/demo.tsx:150-158